# Sort a data.frame using row names of another data.frame

Tags: r, sorting

I need to sort the following data.frame (table 1):

```
X Y
A 1
B 5
C 0
D 3
```

based on the results of another data.frame (table 2):

```
X Y
C 10
B 9
A 8
D 7
```

So, data.frame # 1 ends like this:

```
X Y
C 0
B 5
A 1
D 3
```

How do I do this? I've tried to use:

```
table1[order(row names(table1),]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Subscript out of bound.
```

Comment: Please use correct terminology. A `table` is a very specific data structure in R.

Comment: @user1172558 I noticed that you unaccepted my answer. Is there something wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give the desired result:

```
table1[order(table2$X),]
```